# PHP regex to match command with parameter

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm using this code inside PHP

```
case preg_match('/\/start( .*)?/', $text):
    echo "got you";
break;
```

Using this regex all I need to do is catching following structure:
$text needs to be:

- /start

or

- /start xyz

Where "xyz" stands for random content. These are the two only formats which should be accepted by the regex. For some reason my regex seems to be not working as expected.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Excuse me, I edited.

Comment: What happens with your regex? It works as I'd expect. What is your `switch`  looking like?

Comment: Use a caret to assert beginning of input string `^\/start( .*)?`

Comment: Do you only want to match those two formats? `/start` and `/start xyz` and not something like `/start xyz xyz`? If so, then [is this](https://regex101.com/r/VQzldb/2) what you are looking for?

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/IMjkDg/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
^\/start\s?[\S]*$
```

Here is an example in python [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pzC07J/1):

```
import re

textlist = ["^/start xyz","/start","/start not to match"]

regex = "^/start\s?[\S]*$"

for text in textlist:
    thematch = re.search(regex, text)
    if thematch:
        print ("match found")
    else:
        print ("no match sir!")
```

What it's doing: the line starts with /start and might have space, then there might be any amount of non space (including none) and then the line ends.

Hopefully that helps!

EDIT;
PHP version of this code.

```
$textlist = array("^/start xyz","/start","/start not to match");

$regex = "#^/start\s?[\S]*$#";

foreach($textlist as $text){
    preg_match($regex, $text, $thematch);
    if ($thematch){
        print ("match found\n");
    }else{
        print ("no match sir!\n");
    }
}
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/OFpnG

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any suggestions how to make the regex "require" a second parameter, meaning only things like: `/start xyz` will be accepted (xyz stands for random content)?

Comment: Sure!  If you change the [\S]* to a [\S]+ it will mean that there has to be at least 1 item.  The * means none or any number, the + means 1 or more.

Comment: @seikzer if you found this answer helpful please accept it :)